# How to use preprocessor less for conditional loop

Tags: css, less

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3{
  background: red;
}

#div4, #div5, #div6{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="div0">0</div>
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <div id="div4">4</div>
    <div id="div5">5</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to use less to make the first row of divs red and the second row blue for practice reason.
I studied the documentation and wrote the following code:

```
.generate-colors(6);
.generate-colors(@n, @i:0)when(@i<@n){
  .div@{i}{
    background: red;
  }
  .generate-colors(@n, (@i+1));
}
```

How can I tell less when `@i` is greater than 2, set the background color to blue?

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need LESS for this; you can make use of CSS' **[`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)** pseudo-class in conjunction with `n + 4` to select your second row of elements: `body > div:nth-of-type(n + 4)`. The two existing red elements can be targeted with `n + 2`. This can be seen in the following:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

body > div:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  background: red;
}

body > div:nth-of-type(n + 4) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="div0">0</div>
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
  <div id="div4">4</div>
  <div id="div5">5</div>
</body>

</html>
```

In terms of LESS, you can do this with:

```
body {
    >div {
        &:nth-of-type(n {
            &+2) {
                background: red;
            }
            &+4) {
                background: blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same thing twice:

```
.generate-colors1(2);
.generate-colors1(@n, @i:0)when(@i<@n){
  .div@{i}{
    background: red;
  }
  .generate-colors1(@n, (@i+1));
}
.generate-colors2(6);
.generate-colors2(@n, @i:3)when(@i<@n){
  .div@{i}{
    background: blue;
  }
  .generate-colors2(@n, (@i+1));
}
```